# Access fields in form using vba

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I created a query and a form in Microsoft Access 2010. The form, named TEST, looks as follows:

```
Field1   Field2
a        200
b        400
```

In VBA I tried to access the different fields in the form:

```
Form_TEST.Field1....
```

I want to save the values 200 and 400 in an integer variable (Dim a As Integer) and print it using MsgBox. How can i achieve that??

Comment: So this is a table structured form? In that case you need to save it in an array. Will there always be two rows or can it be more/less?

Comment: well yeah I guess so. I used the GUI menu to create a query and the form assistent to create a form called TEST displaying the resutls from the query. In the VBA editor from a different form, I now want to access the different fields from the TEST form. I don't know how to better explain that. I am a pure beginner :/

Comment: Right. It's going to be a it more difficult than you think. That's why I asked if there always will be two rows. If there are more/less than that, then you need to iterate through the recordset and into a string variable or something. If you only have two rows then you can reference the values using something like this: x = dgvName.Rows(yourRowIndex).Cells(yourColumnIndex).Value

Comment: Yes, it will always be two columns and 4 rows. In VBA, when I type Form_Test.Rows(2).Cells(2).Value, for instance, it doesn't find it. It doesn't even recognise the command .Rows...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Me as the open form and assign the variable if you know the name of the text box.

```
Dim intValue as Integer
'If text box name = TextBox1
intValue = Me.TextBox1.Value
```

Comment: I do not understand that, sorry. I have several forms. From a different form using VBA I want to get the Fields from the form TEST. In VBA I can access the TEST form from my other form using Form_TEST. VBA finds it but I don't know how to access the fields properly

Comment: What is the name of the control on the form that holds the value for the values 200, 400?

Comment: you mean the name of the variable I want to store the values 200 and 400 in?

Comment: No, the Field1 and Field2 are stored in a control on the form.  Field1 and Field 2 would not exist on the form outside of a control.  When you are in design view on the form, if you click on the box where Field 1 and Field2 are and view the properties for the control (F4 if properties are not visible) what type of control is it? Textbox, Subquery, ComboBox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you. 
I understood you created the form with the wizard putting the 2 fields on the form.
What is not clear is the View that you are using.

Well, your form can be displayed in different ways:
  - Single form
  - Continuous forms
  - Datasheet

This is defined by the Default View property.

To see the properties of you form press F4 to see properties and select "Form" as the object that you want to see.

If your form is Single Form or Continuous form you can access the two fields you put on it simply addressing them.

Click on the controls you put on the form and press F4 to see the control name.

**CASE 1 - SINGLE FORM VIEW**
Let's assume that your controls are named Text1 (200) and Text2 (400) and for convenience your form is a single form.

So you can refer to values in the 2 controls writing

```
Dim intText1 As Integer, intText2 As Integer

intText1 = Me.Text1.Value
intText2 = Me.Text2.Value
```

The .Value property is not mandatory cause it's the default property.
At this point you can print out intText1,2 with a MsgBox

```
MsgBox "Text1 = " & CStr(intText1)+ " - Text2 = " & CStr(intText2)
```

This will show Text1 = 200 - Text2 = 400

**CASE 2 - CONTINUOUS FORMS VIEW**
Let's now assume that your view is Continuous form.
So the field that contains 200 and 400 is just one but each record (row) is a form repeated as many times as the number of records.
In this case to access all the records and store them to an array you can use this in the Form_Load event (you can access it by the Control Properties Window - F4)

```
Option Explicit 
Option Base 1                      ' Set the base index for vectors to 1

Dim rst as DAO.Recordset           ' Define a recordset to allocate all query records
Dim Values as Variant              ' Define a variant to allocate all the values

set rst = me.RecordsetClone        ' Copy all records in rst

rst.MoveLast                       ' Go to last record
intNumRecords = rst.RecordCount    ' Count records
rst.MoveFirst                      ' Go back to recordset beginning

ReDim Values(intNumRecords)        ' Resize Values to allocate all values 

i = 1
Do While Not rst.EOF               ' Cycle over all records
    Values(i) = rst!FieldName      ' FieldName is the name of the field of
                                   ' the query that stores 200 and 400    
    i = i + 1                      ' Move to next array element
    rst.MoveNext                   ' Move to next record
Loop

rst.Close                          ' Close recordset
set rst = Nothing                  ' Release memory allocated to rst

for i = 1 To intNumRecords         ' Show easch value as message box
  MsgBox Values(i)
next i
```

**NOTES**
Please NOte that this solution works if you have less than 32767 records to show (the maximum integer with sign that you can store).
The msgbox obliges you to press OK at each value. It's not so comfortable.

Please tell me if it's what you were looking for.

Bye,
Wiz